# filtered Related lists - Soql

Tags: apex, soql, related-list

I am wondering if it is possible to query a record with 2 inner queries of the same related list with different filter.

for exemple :

```
    public static Account getAccountByCustomerNumber(string customerNumber){
    Account account = [SELECT id, Status__c, Person_Account_Id__c, Account_Number__c, 
                         openOrders(SELECT id FROM Orders WHERE Status != 'Closed'),
                         closedOrders(SELECT id from Orders where Status = 'Closed')
                       FROM Account
                       WHERE Account_Number__c = :customerNumber
                       Limit 1];
    return account;
}
```

This is not working but there is an other way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested the core of the query that you provided:

SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM Orders WHERE Status != 'Closed'), (SELECT id from Orders where Status = 'Closed') FROM Account

And the error message is clear

"ERROR at Row:1:Column:78
Cannot follow the same aggregate relationship twice: Orders"

I would advice you quering all orders with their Status field and then filtering them on the front end assuming you need them for a Lighning component or make two methods returning Account with Closed and Opened orders.